# Keeping subtle changes in smart objects

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I'm creating a website in photoshop with artboards. 
So i have for example created a navigation, and created a smart object of that to use across the artboards, this way i only have to edit 1 version to change all items.

I have one problem thou, since this example is for the navigation, i would like to highlight the selected item per artboard, but since its a smart object it gets edited on every artboard.

Is there a way to edit a smart object, but only for the current selected item?

Comment: Not an answer to your question, but it really does sound like you are trying to wireframe/prototype with Photoshop which I really think will cause you a lot of work going forwards. I urge you to look at the likes of Balsamiq, Mockflow and plenty of others.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to edit just one smart object then the simplest way is to create a new instance of it. Just right click on the object layer in layers palette and choose "New smart object via copy". I use this command so often that I assigned a shortcut on it and even assigned a mouse button for this shortcut.

[image]

Flaw of this method is that further changes for original smart object will not be reflected on edited one. I don't know but maybe there is a workaround via external smart objects but I didn't try it myself. As far as I know, there is a plugin which allow to do what you are asking but for Sketch.